# Using Pivot, Groupby and apply to clean up data

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have an issue with **keeping some data** from duplicates and wanting to add valuable information to a new column in the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'id':[1,2,2,3],'company':[1,2,2,1],'bank':['a', 'x', 'y', 'a'], 
    'round': ['seed', 'seed', 'seed', 'series a'], 'funding': [100, 200, 200, 300],
   'date': ['2006-12-01', '2004-09-01', '2004-09-01', '2007-05-01']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id','company', 'round', 'bank', 'funding', 'date'])
print df
```

Yields:

```
   id  company     round   bank    funding        date
0   1        1      seed      a        100  2006-12-01
1   2        2      seed      x        200  2004-09-01
2   2        2      seed      y        200  2004-09-01
3   3        1  series a      a        300  2007-05-01
```

Desired Output:

```
     company   round_0     bank_0   funding_0      date_0    round_1    bank_1  funding_1      date_1 
0          1      seed          a         100  2006-12-01   series a         a        300  2007-05-01
1          2      seed     [x, y]         200  2004-09-01       None      None       None        None
```

I'm thinking that a pivot/melt might work? Along with a groupby('company', 'round')?

Also, I'm open to the idea of changing the dtype for the new bank column list (ie dictionary). And, the integers could be replaced with the "round" column info. Making the columns:

```
company, bank_seed, funding_seed, date_seed, bank_series_a, funding_series_a, date_series_a
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic for bank_0_1, label_1,  bank_1_0, funding_1 and date_1? Why are some of them Nones?

Comment: I'm using 0 indexing, which might be causing some confusion. bank_0_0 is the first bank of the first round. bank_1_0 is the first bank of the second round.  So the first number corresponds to the relative label. Therefore, there are cases where there isn't a second bank who has funded that particular company for that particular label. Does that help?

Comment: Is the number of round always 2? number of bank always 2? or are they variable?

Comment: @Allen Thank you for following up! The number of rounds could be many. As could be the number of banks.

Comment: This means the number of columns of your df will vary. Not quite straightforward.

Comment: To @Allen's point, you're better off picking a number of banks or rounds that is on the high end of possible (like 10, 20?) and setting a fixed number of columns and fill them when necessary, and leave as NaN or None when not. Otherwise, the shape of the df varies in two dimensions which is cumbersome.

Comment: @pshep123 I appreciate your suggestion! Would it be better to have the bank column as a list or dictionary object? That way the dataframe will be categorized by the number of rounds. The len(df.round.unique()) == 9. And therefore would have a known, prefixed dataframe shape.